# How to find BetweennessCentrality[...] for binary edges rather than vertices?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, code-request

I have the following directed graph `g` and can find `BetweennessCentrality[g]` for vertices.

```
ClearAll[g, edges];
g = Graph[{"FIN" \[DirectedEdge] "TSC", "FIN" \[DirectedEdge] "EGW", 
    "TSC" \[DirectedEdge] "FIN", "TSC" \[DirectedEdge] "WHS", 
    "AGF" \[DirectedEdge] "MA2", "EGW" \[DirectedEdge] "MA2", 
    "FIN" \[DirectedEdge] "MA1", "MA2" \[DirectedEdge] "CO12", 
    "CO12" \[DirectedEdge] "WHS", "EGW" \[DirectedEdge] "MA1", 
    "EST" \[DirectedEdge] "AGF"}, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
BetweennessCentrality[g]
```

However, I want to find `BetweennessCentrality` for each edge in `edges`.

```
edges = {"TSC" \[DirectedEdge] "WHS", "EGW" \[DirectedEdge] "MA2", 
   "AGF" \[DirectedEdge] "MA2"};
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Are you looking for [`EdgeBetweennessCentrality`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/EdgeBetweennessCentrality.html)?

Comment: @creidhne: Yes, yes yes...It escaped from my attention that I have used that centrality in past. I was just going to delete my post but you answer came before that. Thanks.